# Grails JQGrid 4.0

Tags: grails, jqgrid, grails-plugin

This problem also concerns my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553615/grails-jqgrid-multiple-grouping) regarding the multiple grouping inside the JQGrid using the `<jqgrid:grid>` tag. But as I later found out [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:change#jqgrid_4.4.0_changes_and_fixes) in the changelog of JQGrid, there might be issues with the grouping feature of JQGrid version 3.8.0. I've tried using the scripting format of JQGrid presented here

So in theory, I would download JQGrid 4.0 and use it in the concerned project.
The question is how can I use the downloaded JQGrid 4.0 files to my project.

Comment: So you've been using an older version of jqGrid in your Grails project and now you want to use an updated version?

Comment: Yes. Is there a JQGrid 4.0 available in the Grails plugin repository?

Comment: I don't know about that.  You could go the more direct route of [downloading jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).  Just put the js file in the webapps/js folder of your grails project and then include the source on whatever gsp pages you need.  You wouldn't get whatever ease of use you get from the Grails plugin, but if you absolutely need the newest version of jqGrid without waiting for a Grails plugin update, then there ya go.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that you can't find a Grails plugin that uses the version of jqGrid that you need, you could go the more direct route of [downloading jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).

Just put the js file in the webapps/js folder of your grails project and then include the source on whatever gsp pages you need. You wouldn't get whatever ease of use you get from the Grails plugin, but if you absolutely need the newest version of jqGrid without waiting for a Grails plugin update, then there ya go.